# Etherscan: Verify and Publish Source Code - Error! Library Name and Address was provided but not used in the contract

Tags: contract-deployment, etherscan, verify, contract-verification

Tried to verify my Smart Contract on Etherscan for Ropsten. Smart Contract is a library which actually also imports another library (which is already verified).

Getting following error

`Error! The Library Name () and Address () was provided but not used in the contract`

When I try using the beta source code verifier

`Exception #3 Occured: Error! The Library_1 Name () and Address () was provided but not used in the contract`

Comment: I actually encountered a similar issue, how about not providing the library and its address, are you able to verify?  Also are all the functions the library use internal?